# Insert statement Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

Here is my table

```
create table reservations (
    ResID int NOT NULL,
    GuestID int,
    HotelID int,
    Check_in DATE,
    Check_out DATE,
    RoomType varchar2(15),
    Price Dec(8,2),
    PRIMARY KEY (ResID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_GuestIDX FOREIGN KEY(GuestID) REFERENCES Guests(GuestID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_HotelID FOREIGN KEY(HotelID) REFERENCES Hotel(HotelID)
);
```

Table was created with no problems. Now Im trying to populate the table

Here is my insert statement

```
insert into reservations (1, 1, 2, '17-DEC-2018', '21-DEC-2018', 'Suite', 87.03);
```

and here is the error that I'm getting

> ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword

What could be the cause for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or missing `values`:

```
insert into reservations
    values (1, 1, 2, '17-DEC-2018', '21-DEC-2018', 'Suite', 87.03);
```

That said, I would recommend writing this as:

```
insert into reservations (ResID, GuestID, HotelID, Check_in, Check_out DATE, RoomType, Price)
    values (1, 1, 2, DATE '2018-12-17', DATE '2018-12-21', 'Suite', 87.03);
```

Note:

- List the columns after the `insert`.  This can really prevent hard-to-debug errors.
- This uses the `DATE` keyword to introduce a date constant.

You can also write this using `SELECT`:

```
insert into reservations (ResID, GuestID, HotelID, Check_in, Check_out DATE, RoomType, Price)
    select 1, 1, 2, DATE '2018-12-17', DATE '2018-12-21', 'Suite', 87.03
    from dual;
```

Comment: adding values worked... I'm an idiot, spent over an hour on this, thank you

Comment: @Riddick: yeah, there's days like that. Please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark under the vote count.

Comment: @gordon Linoff  your answer seems too long haha it can just be values missing